# Crystal Report sends Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report for VS and WFP to view the report on a window.
At the beginning I was facing this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException -- System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: window
```

Then I fixed it following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207692/getting-exception-on-refreshing-the-crystal-report-in-wpf).

Now another vague message appears that I couldn't find for it a solution even following [this](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-57442):

```
System.NullReferenceException -- System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ReportAlbum.RefreshReport()
   at SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.CrystalReportsViewer.RefreshReport_Executed(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e, CommandBinding commandBinding)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(CommandBindingCollection commandBindings, Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
   at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteCore(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Inspector_Reporter_MDK.App.Main() -- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

- My report doesn't have any fields, and of course there are no
  parameters I send.
- All the text are contained in the page size.

My code behind setting the report to print:

```
public void PrintReport()
{
    string reportPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("reports").FullName, "taklif-tansik.rpt");
    //MessageBox.Show(reportPath);
    try
    {
        cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load(reportPath);
        if (cryRpt.IsLoaded)
        {
            ReportPrintWindow = new ReportWindow();
            //cryRpt.Refresh();
            ReportPrintWindow.RptViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            ReportPrintWindow.Show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exEngineException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("exEngineException " + exEngineException.ToString());
    }
}
```

The XAML for Crystal Report viewer:

```
<metro:MetroWindow 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf" x:Class="Inspector_Reporter_MDK.ReportWindow"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer"
        xmlns:metro="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
        BorderThickness="1"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:Inspector_Reporter_MDK"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"Loaded="MetroWindow_Loaded" >
    <Grid >
        <my:CrystalReportsViewer x:Name="RptViewer" />
    </Grid>
</metro:MetroWindow>
```

Code behind for Crystal Report viewer:

```
private void ReportWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RptViewer.Owner = this;
        //MessageBox.Show("RptViewer5");
    }
    catch (Exception exEngineException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("RptViewer " + exEngineException.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Some one voted to close my question, can you specify what wrong am I doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns mismatch run-time dll files of Crystal Report between development machine and the client machine caused this problems:

```
Memory full.
Not enough memory for operation.
```

The second:

```
System.NullReferenceException -- System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**Solution:**

Install the same version used in development machine in client machine. My installed version was `13.0.19`, and client machine `13.0.12`, by deinstalling `13.0.12` and installing a `13.0.19` in the client machine, that solved my problem.

It is better also to install `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable` related to your Visual Studio version.